# get a value Returned from a Dispatcher timer Event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

how do i get a value returned from a event handler at  a calling position??
what i would like to do is something like this

```
             ""  int a = timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => 
                on_time_event(sender, e, draw, shoul_l));   ""


                timer_start = true;
                timer.Interval = 2000;
                timer.Start();
                timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => 
                on_time_event(sender, e, draw, shoul_l));


                private int on_time_event(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e,  
                DrawingContext dcrt, System.Windows.Point Shoudery_lefty)
                 {
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .
                   return a_value;
                  }
```

Comment: How and esp when would you like to receive that value?

Comment: what i all wanted here is just get back a integer value  whenever timer  event handler calls

Comment: from where the event handler is called 
i wanted to do something like this  get a value returned from the  event handler  and store it in a int variable  at define at calling position something like this

int a = timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => 
                on_time_event(sender, e, draw, shoul_l));

Comment: Can you see the timing (timetravelling) problem with that?

Comment: i don't think you are getting me neither do i it should b pretty straight forward for you "How to get a value value returning from a event handler"

Comment: like in c or c++ we used to do like this  int a  = method_Call ();....... method call () {  return 1;}

Answer (score 1):

Place the value on the member variable of the class which launched it. If need be use a lock to allow safe multi-processing. Since this is WPF make the class adhere to the INotifyPropertyChanged and bind it to a control on your screen.

Edit (Per the request of the OP)

I would use a background worker instead of a timer but the concept is the same (be wary not to update GUI controls in a timer, but the BW is designed to allow that).

```
public partial class Window1 : Window,  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    BackgroundWorker bcLoad = new BackgroundWorker();
    private string _data;

    public string Data 
    { 
       get { return _data;} 
       set { _data = value; OnPropertyChanged("Data"); }
    }

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bcLoad.DoWork             += _backgroundWorker_DoWork;
        bcLoad.RunWorkerCompleted += _backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bcLoad.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
        }
    }
 }
```

Here is where the work happens

```
void _backgroundWorker_DoWork( object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e )
{
   e.Result = "Jabberwocky"; 
}
```

And here is where you set the value safely for the GUI.

```
void _backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted( object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e )
{
    Data = (string) e.Result;
}
```

For another example with controls see on my blog : [C# WPF: Threading, Control Updating, Status Bar and Cancel Operations Example All In One](http://omegacoder.com/?p=642)

Comment: a little code might b  very helpful em very amateur when it comes to C# and wpf

Comment: @ahmad05 There is an example, I recommend a background worker, but the concepts are the same.